# Validate REST parameters using Joi in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, rest, hapi.js, joi

I am trying to validate my GET request in a Hapi Node server by using joi package. The Validation is working correctly as expected. However I am struggling to find a way to return an error if there are no parameters passed. Currently if there are no parameters passed it succeeds. Also is there a way to modify the response being sent?

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var Joi = require('joi');

var server = module.exports = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
    host : process.env.HOST,
    port : 3000
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET', 
    path: '/test', 
    config: {
        validate: {
            query: {
                a: Joi.string().regex(/[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}/),
                b: Joi.string(),
                c: Joi.string(),
                d: Joi.string(),
                e: Joi.string()
            }
        }
    },
    handler: function(req, reply) {
        reply('i am a beautiful butterfly');
    }
});

server.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`object.or()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi#objectorpeers) for that:

```
config: {
    validate: {
        query: Joi.object().keys({
            a: Joi.string(),
            b: Joi.string(),
            c: Joi.string(),
            d: Joi.string(),
            e: Joi.string()
        }).or('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
    }
},
```

When none of the query parameters are specified, the following response is returned:

```
{ statusCode: 400,
  error: 'Bad Request',
  message: '"value" must contain at least one of [a, b, c, d, e]',
  validation: { source: 'query', keys: [ 'value' ] } }
```

To modify the response, you can use a custom handler with `failAction()`:

```
config: {
    validate: {
        query: Joi.object().keys({
            a: Joi.string(),
            b: Joi.string(),
            c: Joi.string(),
            d: Joi.string(),
            e: Joi.string()
        }).or('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
        failAction: function(request, reply, source, error) {

            return reply({ message: error.output.payload.message });
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. Is it possible to modify the error message?

Comment: Yes, but again, it should be a separate question. There are many ways to modify the error message. The answer depends on what exactly you want to modify. The error message for just one key? Or you want to modify the output for all validation messages? You want to change the text? Or just the structure?

Comment: I want to modify the structure and send only text

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/hapijs/joi#anyrequired

`joi.string().required()`

Comment: I had seend that before but it didnt work for.  I used it this way Joi.any().required().string() and Joi.string().any().required() and an error points to any not being defined. Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: yes, `any()` just means you can apply to to any of the types. all you need is `joi.string().required()` as i typed above.

Comment: That would make all parameters required. I want atleast one of them to be present

Answer (score 0):

Use `Joi.object().when()` and check if if parameters are present and accordingly make decision wether you want to make it optional or required.

And no you cannot modify the error. You can handle it on server side in hapi `failAction: {}`. Joi has no custom errors functionality.